# A proper way to wait for an event from a concurrent thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I've got an occasional crash that has to do with the improperly finished task on a concurrent thread while an app is transitioning to background.

So I have 3 threads:

1. A (main).
2. B (managed by GCD).
3. C (manually created to process intensive socket operations).

The scenario is the following:

In the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` handler (which is certainly executed on `thread A`) a long-running task is begun on `thread B` to complete all ongoing operations (save an application state, close a socket, etc.). In this task I need to wait until a socket properly finishes its work on `thread C` and only after that to continue with this long-running task.

Below is simplified code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Some synchronous task.
    [stateManager saveState];

    // Here I need to wait until the socket finishes its task.
    ...

    // Continuing of the long-running task.
    ...
}
```

What is the acceptable way to accomplish this task. Is it OK if I do something like this?

```
while (socket.isConnected)
{
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

// Continuing of the long-running task.
```

Or maybe something wrong in my current architecture and I need to use `NSOperation` to serialize asynchronous tasks somehow for example?

**update:** The problem has been solved by using `dispatch_semaphore` [APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) as @Rob Napier suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronization/wait design for cross-thread event signaling (Obj-C)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099801/synchronization-wait-design-for-cross-thread-event-signaling-obj-c)

Comment: It's one of the possible solutions but @Rob Napier offered another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not think of these as threads, and if you're creating a thread with `NSThread` or `performSelectorInBackground:` (or even worse, pthreads), don't do that. Use GCD. GCD creates *queues*. Queues order blocks, which eventually do run on threads, but the threads are an implementation detail and there is not a 1:1 mapping of queues to threads. See [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) for more discussion on that.

To the question of how to wait for some other operation, the tool you probably want is a `dispatch_semaphore`. You create the semaphore and hand it to both operations. Then you call `dispatch_semaphore_wait` when you want to wait for something, and `dispatch_sempahore_signal` when you want to indicate that that something has happened. See [Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) for more example code. The "finite resource" in this case is "the socket." You want to wait until the other part is done using it and returned it to the pool.

Semaphores will work even if you are using manual threading, but I can't emphasize enough that you should not be doing manual threading. All your concurrency should be managed through GCD. This is an important tool to overall concurrency management in iOS.

Comment: Rob thanks for you answer. I'm aware that using GCD whenever it is possible is a good idea besides the fact Apple insists on this. 
But in my case manual thread management is necessary (by `NSThread`) because I need to create 2 long-living readable and writable streams connected to a TCP/IP socket so GCD doesn't fit well in this case.
Thanks for `dispatch_semaphore_*` it was useful!

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe NSThread is necessary here. See CocoaAsyncSocket, particularly its GCD impl: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket. Also https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer. Also see dispatch_io and NSStream. There are lots of ways you can (and should) read from sockets without needing a long-lived thread.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes on GCD-based sockets! I was a little bit confused by legacy code of the current project.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSOperation` with dependencies.
So, you have tasks
A - main thread - aka 'entry point'
B - heavy boy to run in background
C - something else heavy to run after socket finished

1. Your heavy task from "B" is OperationB
2. Assume your socket framework capable of running syncronous in current thread? - then this is your OperationSend
3. Do the rest to do in background - OperationC

there you have a chain of operations, dependent on each other:

OperationB -> OperationSend -> OperationC

Comment: Oleg, thanks. Your solution definitely has the right to live but in my case it requires much more things to redo in the legacy project considering manual threading and non-ARC code. The solution with semaphores has been integrated absolutely seamlessly.